# Fatal: module iscsi_trgt not found -- trying to get my iscsi target to run on debian

Tags: apt, iscsi, kernel

My server info:

> Linux Microknoppix 2.6.39.3 #21 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jul 23 09:48:39 CEST 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

```
modprobe iscsi_trgt
```

results in

```
FATAL: Module iscsi_trgt not found.
```

So I  run

```
# apt-get install module-assistant debhelper
```

then

```
# m-a a-i iscsitarget
```

It fails with error

log:

iscsitarget-source.buildlog.2.6.39.3.1 contents:

```
dh_clean -k
dh_clean: dh_clean -k is deprecated; use dh_prep instead
#/usr/bin/make -C /usr/src/linux KERNEL_SOURCES=/usr/src/linux MODVERSIONS=detect KERNEL=linux-2.6.39.3 KDIR=/usr/src/linux SUBDIRS=/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel modules
/usr/bin/make -C /usr/src/linux SUBDIRS=/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.39.3'
  CC [M]  /usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/tio.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/iscsi.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/nthread.o
  CC [M]  /usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/wthread.o
/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/wthread.c: In function 'worker_thread':
/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/wthread.c:75:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'copy_io_context' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

make[3]: *** [/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel/wthread.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget/kernel] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.39.3'
make[1]: *** [binary-modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/modules/iscsitarget'
make: *** [kdist_build] Error 2
```

I've done most of the work of creating a new partition, volume group, etc..., here is a rough guide to what I've done so far:

Boot to UBCD, open partition manager, resize partition so there is some free space

Create a new partition, but no formatting type /dev/sda3

Boot back into linux root shell

```
aptitude install iscsitarget iscsitarget-modules-`uname -r`
```

First we set up the target (server2):
Open /etc/default/iscsitarget...

```
vi /etc/default/iscsitarget
```

... and set ISCSITARGET_ENABLE to true:

```
ISCSITARGET_ENABLE=true

root@Microknoppix:/sbin# vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda3
No physical volume label read from /dev/sda3
Physical volume "/dev/sda3" successfully created

Volume group "vg0" successfully created
```

Then create 75GB lun under vgo named storage_lun1

```
root@Microknoppix:~# lvcreate -L75G -n storage_lun1 vg0
Logical volume "storage_lun1" created
```

vi /etc/iet/ietd.conf - add the following lines to file
vi /etc/iet/ietd.conf

```
Target iqn.2001-04.com.example:storage.lun1
IncomingUser user p@ssw0rd
OutgoingUser
Lun 0 Path=/dev/vg0/storage_lun1,Type=fileio
Alias LUN1
#MaxConnections 6

root@Microknoppix:/dev/vg0# vi /etc/iet/initiators.allow
```

add to end of file:

```
iqn.2001-04.com.example:storage.lun1 192.168.60.234

/etc/init.d/iscsitarget start 
error Starting iSCSI enterprise target service: FATAL: Module iscsi_trgt not found.
```

So did an: `apt-get install module-assistant debhelper`

then: `m-a a-i iscsitarget` (which also installed kernel headers)

I'd like to get my win7 ultimate box at 192.168.60.234 to connect to the target lun but here is where I am stuck.

Comment: not sure if this is related, but I have a server running as a iscsi target server, and after upgrading Ubuntu to the latest hardware stack, I can no longer access my remote disks. reinstalling/recompiling the driver also fails.. here is my question on askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/511990/iscsitarget-suddenly-broken-after-upgrade-of-the-12-04-hardware-stack

Comment: maybe a bug report is in order? i'll take my issue to the ubuntu IRC channel and see if I can make any headway sometime. If I come up with anything, I'll post back here

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest version from SVN because the one in Debian and Ubuntu usually fails to compile.  I had the same error and the latest-greatest compiles like charm.

```
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/iscsitarget/code/ iscsitarget
```

Or you had better to use [SCST](http://scst.sourceforge.net/target_iscsi.html), because it is more stable.